# Riemannian manifolds with absolute time

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, time

Sorry for my math lacks, I hope you'll be patient even if this question will probably not be clear.

Is possible for an universe to have a curved space and an absolute time?

Would this universe have some physical flaws? (newtonian universe flaws would be invariance for non inertial frames, would a curved one have the same problem?)

What would the equation:

$ds^2_1=a(x_1,y_1)dx^2_1+b(x_1,y_1)dy^2_1=c(x_2,y_2)dx^2_2+d(x_2,y_2)dy^2_2=ds^2_2$

mean? Would the description of this universe be similar in some ways to relativity?

Comment: Imagine a 2D universe like the surface of the Earth with classical physics. This would be a curved manifold with absolute time.  There could be 3D manifolds like that.

Comment: what if a,b,c and d are also functions of t? Does then $ds=e(x,y,t)dx^2+f(x,y,t)dy^2+g(x,y,t)dt^2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

From The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy --
Absolute and Relational Space and Motion: Post-Newtonian Theories

[3.4. Relativistic Best Matching](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#RelaBestMatc)

> The Machian relationists working in the shape dynamics research
> program take this 3+1 approach to the General Theory of Relativity (GTR) as their starting point. They
> thus assume that instantaneous spaces which are the points in
> configuration space have the determinate topology of some closed
> 3-manifold without boundary. Configuration space is the space of
> Riemannian 3-metrics on that 3-manifold. ...
>
> One way to understand the relationship between GTR and shape dynamics
> is that one trades the relativity of simultaneity but absoluteness of
> scales in the former theory, for absolute simultaneity but the
> relativity of scales in the latter.